# Can we give both rect and mask at a time i.e. inside one GrabCut instruction in Android?

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing

If yes.can you please suggest the syntax. And also how to reduce the execution time.

Comment: Are you looking for cropping image?

Comment: I am working on background subtraction for selfies.

Comment: Is this opencv code on Applicaiton layer or NDK layer?

Comment: Did you try:
`Mat uncropped = getUncroppedImage();
Rect roi = new Rect(x, y, width, height);
Mat cropped = new Mat(uncropped, roi);`
Then apply the mask?